# [php][html] cant figure out why there is an error

Tags: php, html

i will very thankful if someone could help me figure out why there is an error on line 37,i tried to change the location of the ""; after echo but nothing worked.... i also tried to put the whole php code in img class="profilePic" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png"/> then to use echo for the name (i want it to change image and name on login.)
code:

```html
<?php
    require ('steamauth/steamauth.php');  
    
 # You would uncomment the line beneath to make it refresh the data every time the page is loaded
 // $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'] = false;
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/stylesheet.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  <script src="./js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <title>CSGOSuprise.party</title>
  <style>
  html
  { background-image: url("images/background.jpg"); }
  </style>
   <body ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false">
   <div class="header">
    <ul>
     <li class="logo"><a href="index.html">CSGOSuprise</a></li>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

   steamlogin();
}  else {
    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
 ?>
<li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </head>
 <body ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="leftMain">
          <div class="profile">
            <div class="profileTop">
<?php echo '<img class="profilePic" src=.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'; ?>
<?php echo '<a href="index.php">' . $steamprofile['personaname'] . '</a>'; ?>
              <div class="medals">
                <img src="./images/medals/italy_small.png" alt="" />
                <img src="./images/medals/dust2_small.png" alt="" />
                <img src="./images/medals/victory_small.png" alt="" />
                <img src="./images/medals/inferno_small.png" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="rankXP">
                <img class="rankXPImage" src="./images/ranks/xp/level39.png" alt="" />
                <span class="rankXPCurrent">Rank 39</span>
                <span class="rankXPNext">Rank 40</span>
                <progress id="xp" value="95" max="100"></progress>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rankComp">
              <img class="rankCompImage" src="./images/ranks/comp/14.png" alt="" />
              <div class="rankCompText">Distinguished Master Guardian</div>
              <div class="wins">
              <img class="rankTrophy" src="./images/trophy.png"/>
              <span class="winNumber">232</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="friendsMain">
      <div class="friendsTop">
       <span>Friends</span>
      </div>
      <div class="friendsList">
         <div class="friendOnline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOnline">8</div>
        </div>
       <div class="friendOnline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOnline">7</div>
       </div>
        <div class="friendOnline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOnline">4</div>
       </div>
       <div class="friendOffline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOffline">6</div>
       </div>
       <div class="friendOffline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOffline">5</div>
       </div>
       <div class="friendOffline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOffline">4</div>
       </div>
                        <div class="friendOffline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOffline">3</div>
       </div>
                               <div class="friendOffline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOffline">2</div>
       </div>
                               <div class="friendOffline">
        <img class="profilePicSmall" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZICYW5z.png" alt="" />
        <div class="friendNameOffline">1</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rightMain">
          <div class="main"></div>
        </div>

     </div>
   
   <script src="./js/script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of

```
<?php echo '<img class="profilePic" src=.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'; ?>
```

you mean

```
<?php echo '<img class="profilePic" src="' . $steamprofile['avatarfull'] . '">'; ?>
```

But you could also do

```
<img class="profilePic" src="<?= $steamprofile['avatarfull'] ?>">
```

Comment: now i have a new error...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 114